# ASP.NET: Question about the column-line-wrapping feature in gridviews

Tags: .net, asp.net, gridview, grid

I have a **ASP.NET gridview** (embedded in a DIV) with several columns. For some columns line wraps are definied and for some not(with ItemStyle.Wrap = true/false). For all columns ItemStyle.Width is set to a specific value. Now I am wondering, that there is a line wrap in a column, where ItemStyle.Wrap = false. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: I think this is a question of what is winning out - the Width property or the Wrap property.

Comment: Usually if you set a specified width, whether you set wrap=false, if your text is wider than the specified width, it will wrap.

Answer (score 1):

The content (text) has to find a way to fit in the column's width you set thus it is wrapped.

Check the column where the **ItemStyle.Wrap = False** and see if the width of the column is less than the length of the content.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField:="Your_data_field" HeaderText="Your_text" sordExpression="Your_sort_expression" ItemStyle-wrap="true" ItemStyle-with="50" />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).